# SqlBulkCopy: Error al insertar un DateTime

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

Tengo una tabla con esta estructura:

```
Create Table dbo.DoesNotMakeSense
(
  Id Int Not Null Identity (1, 1),
  Name NVarChar(100),
  CreationDate DateTime Not Null,

  Constraint PK_DoesNotMakeSense Primary Key Clustered (Id Asc)
)
On [Primary]
```

Y quiero insertar registros usando [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) (porque van a ser muchos). Cuando uso este código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("CreationDate", typeof(DateTime));

    table.Rows.Add("Pepe", DateTime.UtcNow);

    using(var db = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Traducir;User Id=sa;Password=SuperP4ssw0rd!;"))
    using(SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(db))
    {
        copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DoesNotMakeSense";
        db.Open();
        copy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
}
```

Falla con una excepción que dice `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CreationDate', table 'Traducir.dbo.DoesNotMakeSense'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

Evidentemente, esto está haciendo un insert con `NULL` en el `CreationDate`... pero por queeeeee?

Estoy corriendo SQL Server Express en Linux (aunque no creo que haga la diferencia... porque mi sospecha es que SqlBulkCopy no está serializando bien el valor de `CreationDate`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No creo que sea diferencia usar Linux, en este caso usando [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) me parece que necesitarías mapear los campos para que se puedan insertar sin problema en la tabla:

```
using(var db = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Traducir;User Id=sa;Password=SuperP4ssw0rd!;"))
using(SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(db))
using (var colReader = ObjectReader.Create(/*data, membersExposedToReader*/))
{


   SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mName = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Name", "Name");
   SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping mCreationDate = new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("CreationDate", "CreationDate");

    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(mName);   
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(mCreationDate);   
    copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DoesNotMakeSense";

    db.Open();

    copy.WriteToServer(colReader/*table*/);
}
```

Algo [similar a lo realizado en esta pregunta (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127536/how-can-i-use-fast-member-to-bulk-copy-data-into-a-table-with-inconsistent-colum).